# Get index of a specific item from list containing possible duplicates

Tags: c#, search, indexing

okay, I have a list of class objects like so:

```
List<fruit> lst = new List<fruit>();
    lst.Add(orange);
    lst.Add(apple);
    lst.Add(grape);
    lst.Add(grape);
    lst.Add(orange);
    lst.Add(pear);
    lst.Add(apple);
```

I want to be able to ask the list something like
**GetIndex("orange", 2)** and have it return (in this case) the index # for the second instance of object in question (position 4).

This list will be dynamically filled, and it may not even have an orange to begin with.  If it does, I want the instance number of the second parameter.  So I can get the second orange, or get fifth mango, etc.

list.IndexOf(orange) returns the first instance of any duplicates, so I need something else.

Any ideas?

PS: I failed to mention that the first param will be a string!

Comment: Do you mean `GetIndex(orange, 2)`?

Comment: @Neith , do you want the duplicate position always , what happens if it has three items

Comment: @Neith why don't you dictionary and store them as unique values and query later and find the element you want.

Comment: would the dictionary key be the total number of that object, or is it meant to be the index?

Comment: @Neith you should use a Dictionary<string, List<fruit>> where the key of the dictionary is the name of the fruit, and the value is a list with all duplicates. If storage space is an issue, you can use LinkedList instead of List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend classes with your own method for that class, sadly this is not possible for generic classes, so instead you give the type with the method.

```
public static class ListExtension
{
    public static int GetIndex<T>(this List<T> list, T value, int skipMatches = 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            if (list[i].Equals(value))
            {
                skipMatches--;
                if (skipMatches == 0)
                    return i;
            }
        return -1;
    }
}

List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(3);
list.Add(4);
list.Add(5);
list.Add(4);
int secondFour = (int)list.GetIndex(4, 2);
```

Comment: This is almost perfect, but I need to be able to get the object as a string (see edited OP).

Answer (score 3):

```
public static int GetIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> lst, T obj, int index)
{
    return lst.Select((o, i) => new { o, i })
              .Where(x => x.o.Equals(obj))
              .ElementAt(index - 1)
              .i;
}
```

Although it's kind of strange that `index` starts at 1, but the result starts at 0.

Answer (score 2):

```
        int index = lst.IndexOf(orange);
        if (index >= 0)
        {
            index = lst.IndexOf(orange, index + 1);
        }
```

or to make it generic you can use some LINQ:

```
    static int GetIndex(IEnumerable<Fruit> li, Fruit ob, int k)
    {
        var tmp = li.Select((it, i) => new Tuple<int, Fruit>(i, it)).Where(tup => tup.Item2 == ob).Skip(k - 1).FirstOrDefault();
        if (tmp == null)
            return -1;
        else 
            return tmp.Item1;
    }
```

Then call `GetIndex(lst, orange, 2)`

Comment: what happens if he has orange 3 times , it always give second position , does OP going to have always dupliates as two only

Comment: @kobe: This is easy to extend (with a loop) to find the *n*th duplicate.

Comment: @fiver, there is an overload of `Select()` that does the counting of the index for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a generic extension search I just wrote up:

```
public static class ListExtension
{
    public static int GetIndex<T>(this List<T> entity, T what, int find)
    {
        int found = 0;
        int index = -1;

        while ((index = entity.IndexOf(what, (index + 1))) != -1)
        {
            found++;

            if (found == find)
                break;
        }

        return (index);
    }
}
```

All you have to do is call it like so:

```
int index = lst.GetIndex(apple, 2);
```

If the item you are looking for isn't found, it returns -1.

Comment: As intended: The 2nd `T` (or apple) was not found, so it returns -1.

Comment: I mean, in case find==1 and the first of occurrence of entity is at index==0 then your method does not find it, because you start searching at index 1. So I propose to change the initialisation of index from 0 to -1. Unless I'm mistaken....

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = list.Select((x, i) => new { x, i })
                  .Where(t => t.x == fruit)
                  .Skip(k - 1)
                  .Select(t => t.i)
                  .First();
```

Comment: This is more efficient than it looks, as long as an exception is the desired results when there aren't enough matches.

Comment: Why call `Skip()` and then `First()` when you can do the same more clearly with `ElementAt()`?

Comment: @svick: I just modified the answer by @BrokenGlass slightly (which used Skip and FirstOrDefault) and left the solution with ElementAt for you to post (and receive rep for) ;-)

Comment: This is a great answer!  Just change it to `.Select(t => (int?)t.i)` and make it `.FirstOrDefault()` to account for missing values.  Then you can `return (result.HasValue ? result.Value : -1);` to make it work like `IndexOf()`.

Comment: @mattmc3 I'm not familiar with this notation...care to write up what you mean?

Comment: @Neith - Sure.  See my version of dtb's answer.

Answer (score 0):

An extension of dtb's answer to account for when you don't find the value you're looking for:

```
public int GetIndex<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, T item, int itemNum) {
    // result is a nullable int containing the index
    var result = list.Select((x, i) => new { x, i })
                     .Where(t => item.Equals(t.x))
                     .Skip(itemNum - 1)
                     .Select(t => (int?)t.i)
                     .FirstOrDefault();
    // return -1 when item was not found
    return (result.HasValue ? result.Value : -1);
}
```